# invalid syntax when importing ROM in gym-retro (google colab)

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I want to use google colab to run a DL code and learn about it.
the code use the gym-retro package. I downloaded the ROM and uploaded it to the google colab workspace.
but when I try to use it, it fails! anyonw knows why? I used the exact syntax from the documentation.

```
!pip install gym-retro
import retro
python3 -m retro.import '/content/Space Invaders (USA).a26'

  File "<ipython-input-13-14cfeb7bbb8f>", line 3
    python3 -m retro.import '/content/Space Invaders (USA).a26'
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**EDIT**:

ok, looks like I needed a "!" before the command. now there is a new problem:

```
Imported 0 games
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the directory instead of the file:

> python3 -m retro.import /path/to/your/ROMs/directory/

Link to the doc:
https://retro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#importing-roms

Answer (score 0):

"pip3 install gym-retro" is the code for the commandline like commandprompt or terminal to install gym retro

be warned that it only works for python v 3.6/3.7/3.8
but not the current 3.9

also you are not going to be able to import space invaders with the extension of .a26 will not work

for rom extensions that will work see https://retro.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration.html#supported-roms